# Spring Boot 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, view, thymeleaf

Делаю CRUD приложение на Spring Boot с Thymeleaf. При попытке выполнить PATCH запрос выдается ошибка `404 not found`. При этом браузер почему-то направляет на адрес "/update", а не на "/update/id", как должно быть. POST запрос при этом выполняется нормально.
Пробовал в PatchMapping методе вместо `redirect:` указывать `index`, но тогда он сначала возвращает страницу с одной единственной записью и требует подтверждения для сохранения, а мне это не надо.
Контроллер:

```
package com.example.demo6.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PatchMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.example.demo6.entities.Dog;
import com.example.demo6.service.DogService;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;

@Controller
@RequestMapping
public class DogController extends AbstractController<Dog, DogService> {
    private DogService dogService;
    
    @Autowired
    public DogController(DogService service, DogService dogService) {
        super(service);
        this.dogService = dogService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String index(Model model) {  
        model.addAttribute("dog", new Dog());
        model.addAttribute("dogs", dogService.findAll());
        return "index";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public String edit(Model model, @PathVariable("id") int id) {       
        model.addAttribute("dog", dogService.findById(id));
        return "editdog";
        
    }
    
    @PostMapping
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("dog")@Valid Dog dog, Model model) { 
        dogService.save(dog);
        return "redirect:";
    }
    
    @PatchMapping("/update/{id}")
    public String update(@ModelAttribute("dog")@Valid Dog updatedDog, @PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {    
        dogService.update(id, updatedDog);
        return "redirect:";
    }
    
}
```

Страница редактирования:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Изменить собаку</title>
 <style>
   table { 
    width: 100%; 
    border: 4px double black; 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
   }
   th { 
    text-align: left; 
    background: #ccc; 
    padding: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
   }
   td { 
    padding: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
   }
  </style>
  
</head>
<body>
    <table><tr><form id="edit" modelAttribute="dog" th:method="PATCH" th:object:"${dog}" th:action="@{/update/{id}(id=${dog.getId()})}">
                     
                    <td th:text="${dog.id}"></td>
                    
                    <td><input type="text" th:text="${dog.nickname}" th:field="*{dog.nickname}"/></td>
                    
                    <td><input type="text" th:text="${dog.name}" th:field="*{dog.name}"/></td>
                    
                    <td><select th:field="*{dog.gender}">
                            <option th:each="genderType : ${T(com.example.demo6.entities.Dog.Gender).values()}" 
                            th:value="${genderType}" th:text="${genderType.type}"></option>
                        </select></td>
                    
                    <td><select th:field="*{dog.breed}">
                            <option th:each="breedType : ${T(com.example.demo6.entities.Dog.Breed).values()}" 
                                th:value="${breedType}" th:text="${breedType.type}"></option>
                        </select></td>
                    
                    <td><input type="date" th:field="*{dog.dateOfBirth}"/></td>
                    
                    <td><input type="number" th:field="*{dog.puppies}"/></td>
                    
                    
                    <td><input type="submit" id="toedit" value="Изменить" form="edit"/></td>                                        
                </form></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Главная:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Собаки</title>
 <style>
   table { 
    width: 100%; 
    border: 4px double black; 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
   }
   th { 
    text-align: left; 
    background: #ccc; 
    padding: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
   }
   td { 
    padding: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
   }
  </style>
  
</head>
<body>
    
<div th:if="${isUserAuth}">Выйти</div>
<div th:unless="${isUserAuth}">Войти</div>
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
 <a href="/logout">Logout</a>  
</div>

<div sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()">
    <p>Hello, guest! Please <a href="/login">Login</a> or <a href="/signup">SignUp</a></p> 
</div>

<div>Выберите сущность:
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="radio" id="dogChoice" value="dog"/><label for="dogChoice">Собаки</label>
        </form>
</div>
<table border="1" color="black" border-collapse="collapse">
    <tr>
        <td><b>ID</b></td>
        <td><b>Кличка</b></td>
        <td><b>Имя</b></td>
        <td><b>Пол</b></td>
        <td><b>Порода</b></td>
        <td><b>Дата рождения</b></td>
        <td><b>Щенки</b></td>
        <td><b>Добавлено</b></td>
        <td><b>Изменено</b></td>
        <td>Изменить</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <form modelAttribute="dog" th:method="POST" th:object:"${dog}" th:action="@{/}" action="#">
            <td><input type="submit" value="Добавить"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.nickname}"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.name}"/></td>
            <td><select th:field="*{dog.gender}">
                    <option th:each="genderType : ${T(com.example.demo6.entities.Dog.Gender).values()}" 
                        th:value="${genderType}" th:text="${genderType.type}"></option>
                </select></td>
            <td><select th:field="*{dog.breed}">
                    <option th:each="breedType : ${T(com.example.demo6.entities.Dog.Breed).values()}" 
                        th:value="${breedType}" th:text="${breedType.type}"></option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="date" th:field="*{dog.dateOfBirth}"/></td>
            <td><input type="number" th:field="*{dog.puppies}"/></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            </form>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="dog : ${dogs}">
            
                <form id="edit" modelAttribute="dog" th:method="PATCH" th:object:"${dog}" th:action="@{/}" action="#">
                     
                    <td th:text="${dog.id}"></td>
                    <td th:unless="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.nickname}"></td>
                    <td th:if="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.nickname}"><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.nickname}"/></td>
                    <td th:unless="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.name}"></td>
                    <td th:if="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.name}"><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.name}"/></td>
                    <td th:unless="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.gender.getType()}"></td>
                    <td th:if="${dog.isModifying}"><select th:field="*{dog.gender}">
                            <option th:each="genderType : ${T(com.example.demo6.entities.Dog.Gender).values()}" 
                            th:value="${genderType}" th:text="${genderType.type}"></option>
                        </select></td>
                    <td th:unless="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.breed.getType()}"></td>
                    <td th:if="${dog.isModifying}"><select th:field="*{dog.breed}">
                            <option th:each="breedType : ${T(com.example.demo6.entities.Dog.Breed).values()}" 
                                th:value="${breedType}" th:text="${breedType.type}"></option>
                        </select></td>
                    <td th:unless="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.dateOfBirth}"></td>
                    <td th:if="${dog.isModifying}"><input type="date" th:field="*{dog.dateOfBirth}"/></td>
                    <td th:unless="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.puppies}"></td>
                    <td th:if="${dog.isModifying}"><input type="number" th:field="*{dog.puppies}"/></td>
                    <td th:unless="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.modifiedAt}"></td>
                    <td th:unless="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.createdAt}"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="toedit" value="Изменить" onclick="toEdit()" form="edit"/></td>                                         
                </form>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <form modelAttribute="dog" th:method="POST" th:object:"${dog}" th:action="@{/}" action="#">
                    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.id}" id="dog.id"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.nickname}" id="dog.nickname"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.name}" id="dog.name"/></td>
                        <td><select th:field="*{dog.gender}" id="dog.gender">
                                <option th:each="genderType : ${T(com.example.demo6.entities.Dog.Gender).values()}" 
                                    th:value="${genderType}" th:text="${genderType.type}"></option>
                            </select></td>
                        <td><select th:field="*{dog.breed}" id="dog.breed">
                                <option th:each="breedType : ${T(com.example.demo6.entities.Dog.Breed).values()}" 
                                    th:value="${breedType}" th:text="${breedType.type}"></option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td><input type="date" th:field="*{dog.dateOfBirth}" id="dog.dateOfBirth"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.puppies}" id="dog.puppies"/></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Сохранить"/></td>
                        <td><input type="reset" value="Сброс"/></td>
                        <td><input type="button" value="Отменить"/></td>
                        
                    </form>
       
                
        
            </tr>
 </table>
 <script>
        toedit.onclick = function()
            {
                document.getElementById('eachDog').innerHTML = document.getElementById(document.getElementById('edit').value).innerHTML;
                alert("pashet");
            };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, в параметре нужно вместо `(id=${dog.getId()})` писать без использования метода: `(id=${dog.id})`, тогда направить на нужный контроллер.